# Merge 2 SELECT queries using case function

Tags: mysql, select, case

My 1st query is:

```
SELECT c.icareno, c.operation_date, p.prod_cat_name, prod.product_name, c.nename,
       c.operation_desc, u.uname, c.oper_severity, c.rfc_status 
  FROM ccb c, product_cat p, userlogininfo u, productname prod 
 WHERE c.prod_cat = p.prod_cat_id 
   AND c.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
   AND c.oper_leader = u.userid 
   AND c.ccb_id <= 279
ORDER BY c.operation_date;
```

2nd query is

```
SELECT c.icareno, c.operation_date, p.prod_cat_name, prod.product_name, node.node_name, 
       c.operation_desc, u.uname, c.oper_severity, c.rfc_status 
  FROM ccb c, product_cat p, userlogininfo u, productname prod, node_list node
 WHERE c.prod_cat = p.prod_cat_id 
   AND c.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
   AND c.oper_leader = u.userid 
   AND c.ccb_id > 279 
   AND c.nename = node.node_id
ORDER BY c.operation_date;
```

I want to merge these 2 queries using the CASE function? Can anyone help how I can merge it?

Sample data:

[image]

Comment: `union` or `union all` is what you’re probably looking for. I would recommend including maybe some example outputs of what you want it to look like.

Comment: Whatever extra info, just edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

```
and ((c.ccb_id > 279 AND c.nename =    node.node_id) or c.ccb_id <= 279)
```